# Is this scheme reduced?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $O=\mathbb C[X]$ and denote by $SL_r(O)_1\subset SL_r(O)$ the set of matrices of this form $$I_r+XM(X), \text{ for some matrix } M(X)$$

Consider the involution $\sigma$ on $SL_r(O)_1$ given by $M(X)\rightarrow ^tM(-X)^{-1}$.

> Quastion: Is $SL_r(O)_1^\sigma$ (the fixed locus) reduced?

My idea was to write this group as direct limit of schemes $V_N^\sigma\subset SL_r(O)_1^\sigma$ consisting of matrices of degree in $X$ at most $N$ and than show that $V_N$ is reduced. $V_N^\sigma$ can be seen as subschemes of the locus $V_N$ of matrices of degree at most $N$ whose equation is $$^tM(-X)M(X)=1$$

Is this $V_N^\sigma$ reduced?